# Call Controller Action from Startup Configure method in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an Angular application with .Net Core backend, and I also use Server Side Rendering using `spa.UseSpaPrerendering`in startup file.

Some of the urls in my app requires data to be fetched from database. And for that during server side rendering my Angular application makes request to the server, fetch data and generate response using that data. This additional request can be avoided if I pass the data using `SpaPrerenderingOptions.SupplyData` in startup file, but for that I have to call the Controller Action method from the Configure method of Startup file.

Can anyone please guide how to achieve this?

**Update**
I tried below approach to pass data from repository, but apiData is always null in my Angular App.

```
options.SupplyData = async (context, data) =>
                    {
                        var request = context.Request;

                        if (request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/articles/detail"))
                        {
                            string id = request.Path.ToString().Split('/').Last();

                            int articleId = 0;

                            Int32.TryParse(id, out articleId);

                            var articleService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IArticlesRepository>();
                            var article = await articlesService.Details(articleId);
                            data.Add("apiData", article.ToString());
                        }
                    };
```

**Update 2**
I was able to make it work using below approach, but it has a drawback, that it makes the code synchronous.

```
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            var request = context.Request;

            if (request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/articles/article"))
            {
                string id = request.Path.ToString().Split('/').Last();

                int articleId = 0;

                Int32.TryParse(id, out articleId);

                var articleService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IArticlesRepository>();
                var article = articlesService.Article(articleId).Result;
                requestData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(article);

            }
            return next();
        });
```

**If I make it async**

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var request = context.Request;

            if (request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/articles/article"))
            {
                string id = request.Path.ToString().Split('/').Last();

                int articleId = 0;

                Int32.TryParse(id, out articleId);

                var articleService = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IArticlesRepository>();
                var article = await articlesService.Article(articleId);
                requestData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(article);

            }

        });
```

The next code block `app.UseSpa(spa =>` never gets executed.

Comment: Am I understanding your app correctly: The server-side starts, which starts the SPA prerenderer. But before it can start hosting the SPA and the API correctly, the SPA needs to make a call to the API to get some data from the database?

Comment: Looks like what you are trying to do is obsolete, What I can think of is you could refactor your code and pull the things that require db fetching and make them into   caching service, then resolve it during application startup and run it once. With ASP.NET Core this should be done in Program.cs's Main method. Never use it in StartUp.cs. Please check this link too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747892/questions-on-net-core-3-1-angular-ssr-spa-usespaprerendering-alternative

Comment: @JamieTaylor yes you are right, I need to call a controller action method and get results in my startup, so that I can pass it when calling spa.UseSpaPrerendering

Comment: I have updated the question with the approach I tried, but still having some issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Questions on .NET Core 3.1 & Angular SSR spa.UseSpaPrerendering alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59747892/questions-on-net-core-3-1-angular-ssr-spa-usespaprerendering-alternative)

Comment: Not really, I am aware that the UseSpaPrerendering has been mark as Obsolete, but its still supported.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you want to do is possible. The server may not have started by the time that the SpaServices start. Meaning that the .NET Core WebApi code won't have been fully instantiated, and may not be able to deal with your request. Might I recommend splitting your app into two separate applications (one for the front end and one for the back)? That way, you can start the API fully before it's needed

Comment: Can you please take a look at Update 2, and suggest any work around?